# Spring JdbcTemplate implementation of @PrePersist and @PreUpdate for audit columns

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jpa, jdbctemplate

If I were using Hibernate/JPA I would use @PrePersist and @PreUpdate (or @PostPersist and @PostUpdate) to put data into audit columns before (or after) every update/insert.  Using only Spring JdbcTemplate, though, what is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

As far is I know there is no lifecycle mechanism attached to JdbcTemplate (which actually makes sense because that class is just a utility that simplifies the Jdbc workflow).

If you use JdbcTemplate, you would have to perform auditing operations manually

Answer (score 0):

Use AOP and add @Before advice to the methods that persist or update data.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the ideas.  For Oracle specifically, I was able to implement this by returning a key from the initial insert (using Spring's KeyHolder) or initial update (using Oracle's RETURNING INTO clause) representing the affected row, then executing a follow-up query to update the audit columns.  The code is in an abstract base DAO that is subclassed by the DAOs needing this functionality.

```
@Inject
private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedJdbc;

public Long insert(String sql, Map<String, Object> params, String table, String keyColumn) {
    SqlParameterSource paramSource = new MapSqlParameterSource(params);
    KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
    int numberOfAffectedRows = namedJdbc.update(sql, paramSource, keyHolder, new String[]{keyColumn});
    Long key = (numberOfAffectedRows == 1) ? keyHolder.getKey().longValue() : -1L;
    if (key != -1) {
        updateAuditColumns(table, keyColumn, key.toString(), true);
    }
    return key;
}

public void insert(String sql, Map<String, Object> params, String table) {
    SqlParameterSource paramSource = new MapSqlParameterSource(params);
    KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
    int numberOfAffectedRows = namedJdbc.update(sql, paramSource, keyHolder);
    ROWID rowId = (numberOfAffectedRows == 1) ? (ROWID) keyHolder.getKeys().get("ROWID") : null;
    if (rowId != null) {
        updateAuditColumns(table, "ROWID", rowId.stringValue(), true);
    }
}

public void update(String sql, Map<String, Object> params, String table) {
    sql += " returning ROWID into ?";//Oracle specific
    final String finalSql = sql;
    final Map<String, Object> finalParams = params;

    String rowId = namedJdbc.getJdbcOperations().execute(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
        @Override
        public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
            OraclePreparedStatement stmt = (OraclePreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(finalSql);
            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : finalParams.entrySet()) {
                stmt.setObjectAtName(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());//jdbc driver will choose type
            }
            stmt.registerReturnParameter(finalParams.entrySet().size()+1, OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
            return stmt;
        }
    }, new PreparedStatementCallback<String>() {
        @Override
        public String doInPreparedStatement(PreparedStatement s) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
            OraclePreparedStatement stmt = (OraclePreparedStatement) s;
            stmt.executeUpdate();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.getReturnResultSet();
            try {
                if (rs.next()) {
                    return rs.getString(1);
                }
                throw new IllegalStateException("ROWID not returned");
            } finally {
                rs.close();
            }
        }
    });

    if (rowId != null) {
        updateAuditColumns(table, "ROWID", rowId, false);
    }
}
```